# Picasso - java.lang.NullPointerException: key == null

Tags: android, android-asynctask, image-caching, picasso

I am using [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) in one of my application to download a lot of images for future usages as the application will be totally offline mode after login.

So after successful login I was trying to download the images in a AsyncTask with a Progress

To achieve the goal I have written the following code to download a bunch of images

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class CacheActivity extends Activity {
    int size = 0;
    final List<String> urls = new ArrayList<String>();
    int totalImageSize;
    static Picasso picasso;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cache);

        Collections.addAll(urls, Data.URLS);
        Collections.addAll(urls, Data.URLS);
        Collections.addAll(urls, Data.URLS);
        totalImageSize = urls.size();

        picasso = Picasso.with(CacheActivity.this);
        picasso.setDebugging(true);

        new TestTask().execute();

    }

    public class TestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>

    {
        ProgressDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(CacheActivity.this);
            dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            dialog.setMax(totalImageSize);
            dialog.setMessage("1 - 100");
            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            for (Iterator iterator = urls.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                final String url = (String) iterator.next();

                try {
                    picasso.load(url).get();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                size = size + 1;
                publishProgress(size);

            System.out.println("CacheActivity.TestTask.doInBackground()");

            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

    }

}
```

But when I am running the app I am getting the following error

```
07-30 12:55:42.334: W/System.err(2369): java.lang.NullPointerException: key == null
07-30 12:55:42.334: W/System.err(2369):     at com.squareup.picasso.LruCache.get(LruCache.java:50)
07-30 12:55:42.334: W/System.err(2369):     at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.hunt(BitmapHunter.java:101)
07-30 12:55:42.334: W/System.err(2369):     at com.squareup.picasso.RequestBuilder.get(RequestBuilder.java:305)
07-30 12:55:42.344: W/System.err(2369):     at com.example.picasso.CacheActivity$TestTask.doInBackground(CacheActivity.java:61)
07-30 12:55:42.344: W/System.err(2369):     at com.example.picasso.CacheActivity$TestTask.doInBackground(CacheActivity.java:1)
07-30 12:55:42.344: W/System.err(2369):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
07-30 12:55:42.344: W/System.err(2369):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
07-30 12:55:42.344: W/System.err(2369):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
07-30 12:55:42.344: W/System.err(2369):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
07-30 12:55:42.344: W/System.err(2369):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
07-30 12:55:42.344: W/System.err(2369):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
07-30 12:55:42.344: W/System.err(2369):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-30 12:55:42.334: W/System.err(2369): java.lang.NullPointerException: key == null
07-30 12:55:42.334: W/System.err(2369):     at com.squareup.picasso.LruCache.get(LruCache.java:50)
07-30 12:55:42.334: W/System.err(2369):     at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.hunt(BitmapHunter.java:101)
07-30 12:55:42.334: W/System.err(2369):     at com.squareup.picasso.RequestBuilder.get(RequestBuilder.java:305)
07-30 12:55:42.344: W/System.err(2369):     at com.example.picasso.CacheActivity$TestTask.doInBackground(CacheActivity.java:61)
07-30 12:55:42.344: W/System.err(2369):     at com.example.picasso.CacheActivity$TestTask.doInBackground(CacheActivity.java:1)
07-30 12:55:42.344: W/System.err(2369):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
07-30 12:55:42.344: W/System.err(2369):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
07-30 12:55:42.344: W/System.err(2369):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
07-30 12:55:42.344: W/System.err(2369):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
07-30 12:55:42.344: W/System.err(2369):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
07-30 12:55:42.344: W/System.err(2369):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
07-30 12:55:42.344: W/System.err(2369):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong ?

Comment: I'm doing something similar HERE!!!http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808114/picasso-loading-of-image-spawned-inside-asynctask

Answer (score 0):

Hmm that's an interesting problem. It seems like you are using Picasso 2.0 also. Have you confirmed you are not passing null?

I'd need a sample app (including the URLs) to debug this. Can you pack it up and attach?

**edit**: This is now fixed in Picasso 2.0.

https://github.com/square/picasso

Comment: @Tanmay Mandal get [picasso2](https://twitter.com/dnkoutso/status/369987447834173440) here